# Not able to run fw_printenv command in platform.sh scipt while doing firmware upgrade in openwrt

Tags: html, openwrt

I am not able to run fw_printenv and fw_setenv commands in platform.sh and common.sh script simultaneously while doing the firmware upgrade in openwrt. 
We have 2 partitions on our board(primary and secondary). If we are in the primary partition then we want to upgrade in the secondary partition. For that, I have to set 1 boot arguments but not able to run above-mentioned command. Can anyone help me with this?
Below is the logs:
 fw_printenv
ash: fw_printenv: not found
 cut -b 9
 grep primary

Answer (score 0):

From the logs, it's clear that the desired utilities are not present in the system.
fw_printenv and fw_setenv are part of u-boot-fw-utils, you need to include that package in your firmware to use them.
You can select the package using

```
make menuconfig
```